# Condorcet's jury theorem - non asymptotic part

Tags: probability, decision-theory

Im trying to proof the non asymptotic part of Condorcet's jury theorem:

"In a homogeneous committee composed of n=2k+1 independent experts with the same expertise
0.5 < , any addition of an even number of specialists with expertise  increases the probability of the majority rule being right. "

I tried it by induction on the number of added experts but I get too complicated equations of binomial probability.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet%27s_jury_theorem

Here is a proof in wikipedia but I am don't understand it correctness

Thanks

Comment: I'd never heard of this theorem, so here's a link in case anyone else needs it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet%27s_jury_theorem

Comment: Yes and there are already proofs inside the wiki link.

Comment: Can you verify the proof? I don't understand why showing that  The probability that they change an incorrect majority to a correct majority is bigger than  the probability that they change a correct majority to an incorrect majority proving the statement. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing new here, I just follow the proof from wiki. Let $X_n \sim \text{Binomial}(n, p)$. Note that $X_{2k+3}$ has the same distribution as $X_{2k+1} + X_2$ if $X_{2k+1}, X_2$ are independent. We want to prove
$$ \Pr\{X_{2k+1} \geq k+1\} < \Pr\{X_{2k+3} \geq k+2\} $$
when $\displaystyle p > \frac {1} {2}$, for all $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$

Now we list the cases (events) in which only the first two cases the additional $X_2$ will change the majority of $X_{2k+1}$:

1. $M_1 = \{X_{2k+1} = k, X_2 = 2\}$
2. $M_2 = \{X_{2k+1} = k+1, X_2 = 0\}$
3. $M_3 = \{X_{2k+1} = k, X_2 \leq 1\}$
4. $M_4 = \{X_{2k+1} = k+1, X_2 \geq 1\}$
5. $M_5 = \{X_{2k+1} \leq k-1\}$
6. $M_6 = \{X_{2k+1} \geq k+2\}$

So by law of total probability,

$$ \begin{align}
&~ \Pr\{X_{2k+3} \geq k + 2\} \\
=&~ \Pr\{X_{2k+1} + X_2 \geq k + 2\} \\
= &~ \sum_{i=1}^6 \Pr\{X_{2k+1} + X_2 \geq k + 2|M_i\}\Pr\{M_i\} \\
= &~ 1 \times \Pr\{X_{2k+1} = k\}\Pr\{X_2 = 2\} \\
&~ + 0 \times \Pr\{X_{2k+1} = k+1\}\Pr\{X_2 = 0\} \\
&~ + 0 \times \Pr\{X_{2k+1} = k\}\Pr\{X_2 \leq 1\} \\
&~ + 1 \times \Pr\{X_{2k+1} = k+1\}\Pr\{X_2 \geq 1\} \\
&~ + 0 \times \Pr\{X_{2k+1} \leq k-1\} \\
&~ + 1 \times \Pr\{X_{2k+1} \geq k+2\} \\
= &~ \binom{2k+1} {k} p^k (1-p)^{k+1} p^2 + \Pr\{X_{2k+1} = k+1\}(1 - (1-p)^2)
+ \Pr\{X_{2k+1} \geq k+2\} \\
= &~\Pr\{X_{2k+1} \geq k+1\} + \binom{2k+1} {k} p^{k+2} (1-p)^{k+1}
- \binom{2k+1} {k} p^{k+1} (1-p)^{k} (1-p)^2 \\
= &~\Pr\{X_{2k+1} \geq k+1\} + \binom{2k+1} {k} p^{k+1} (1-p)^{k+1} (p - (1-p)) \\
> &~\Pr\{X_{2k+1} \geq k+1\}
\end{align}$$

So that is just what we want.